# Reference Java DLL in C# Assembly?

Tags: c#, java, dll, reference, assemblies

There are instructions [here](http://anastasiosyal.com/archive/2009/01/11/18.aspx) to create a C# assembly using the SimMetrics library. The link they provided to this library is at [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/). It looks like the most recent version of the SimMetrics library was created in Java. Is it possibly to compile java code and then reference it in C# to be used as an assembly in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is

1. compile the java as J# (now obsolete and largely unsupported) with minimal code changes.

   - this is very dependent on how much of the libraries are used.
2. convert the code to c# (idiomatic or otherwise)

   - this can sometimes be fairly easy on highly mathematical code. As an advantage the java code likely assumes 16 bit unicode as well.
3. use something like [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) to host the java byte code within the CLR

   - this may be outright impossible with the sql server hosted runtime, certainly I would think the performance would be poor (since you would have to 'thunk' across the hosting barrier on each call.

The SF page [strongly](http://sourceforge.net/news/?group_id=123463) [implies](http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?forum_id=615509) that there is both a java and a .net release.
Here's the latest [.net release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/files/simmetrics.NET%20%26amp%3Bamp%3B%20phonetics.NET/SimMetricsv1.5-2006-09-24.zip) and [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/files/simmetrics.NET%20%26amp%3Bamp%3B%20phonetics.NET/SimMetrics-v1.5-Documentation-2006-09-24.zip)

However based on the read me file in that

> This is an updated version of the original .NET implementation and not a conversion of the newest Java Code.

The .Net implementation is largely c# so you could diff the recent changes in the java implementation then attempt to recreate them in the .Net code. Since the conversion to c# seems to be largely a direct copy with only basic consideration given to idiomatic c# (camel casing, properties and parameter names) you stand a good chance of being able to do this.

If you do consider submitting the changes as a patch, this would give you a chance of getting someone else to validate your changes and may jump start the .Net side of the project to be kept more closely in sync in future.

Comment: The last .NET release was Sept 24 2006, the last Java Feb 07 2007.

Comment: the src implies it is supplied as platform agnostic. It may be that building from source gets you the latest version in .Net.

Comment: ah no - clearly it's done as a fork, added suggestion on what to do with that

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! I'll delve into some Java and see if I can convert the remaining Java code to .Net